The tables are getting printed on console but not on the screen
I have created a machine learning model and am working on a React application with a Flask backend. I am passing the API data from the backend to the frontend. Although there are no errors, the tables are not displaying on the screen.
Below is my react file:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [tables, setTables] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/tables');
        console.log('API response:', response.data);
        setTables(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   if (tables) {
  //     console.log('Tables state updated:', tables);
  //   }
  // }, [tables]);

  if (!tables) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Agricultural Data</h1>

      {tables.final_table && tables.final_table.length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <h2>Table 1: Max and Min Production</h2>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Crop With Max Production</th>
                <th>Crop With Min Production</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {tables.final_table.map((row, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{row.Year}</td>
                  <td>{row.CropWithMaxProd}</td>
                  <td>{row.CropWithMinProd}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No data available for Table 1</p>
      )}

      {tables.final_table2 && tables.final_table2.length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <h2>Table 2: Average Yield and Cultivation Area</h2>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Crop Name</th>
                <th>Average Yield (Kg/Ha)</th>
                <th>Average Cultivation Area (Ha)</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {tables.final_table2.map((row, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{row['Crop Name']}</td>  {/* Use dot notation */}
                  <td>{row['Average Yield (Kg/Ha)']}</td>
                  <td>{row['Average Cultivation Area (Ha)']}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No data available for Table 2</p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


Below is my flask file
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/api/tables')
def get_tables():
    # Load the data
    data = pd.read_csv("E:/MyApps/CropData/flask-server/Dataset/ManufacIndiaAgroDataset.csv")
    
    # Data cleaning and processing
    data['Crop Production (UOM:t(Tonnes))'] = data['Crop Production (UOM:t(Tonnes))'].fillna(0)
    data['Yield Of Crops (UOM:Kg/Ha(KilogramperHectare))'] = data['Yield Of Crops (UOM:Kg/Ha(KilogramperHectare))'].fillna(0)
    data['Area Under Cultivation (UOM:Ha(Hectares))'] = data['Area Under Cultivation (UOM:Ha(Hectares))'].fillna(0)
    
    # Group data by year and find max and min production crops
    year_group = data.groupby('Year')[['Crop Production (UOM:t(Tonnes))']].agg(['max', 'min']).reset_index()
    year_group.columns = ['Year', 'MaxProd', 'MinProd']
    
    # Merge with original data to get crop names
    merged_max = pd.merge(year_group, data, left_on=['Year', 'MaxProd'], right_on=['Year', 'Crop Production (UOM:t(Tonnes))'])
    merged_min = pd.merge(year_group, data, left_on=['Year', 'MinProd'], right_on=['Year', 'Crop Production (UOM:t(Tonnes))'])
    
    final_table = pd.DataFrame({
        'Year': merged_max['Year'],
        'CropWithMaxProd': merged_max['Crop Name'],
        'CropWithMinProd': merged_min['Crop Name']
    })
    
    # Calculating the average value and rounding off for 3 digits
    average_yield = data.groupby('Crop Name')['Yield Of Crops (UOM:Kg/Ha(KilogramperHectare))'].mean().round(3)
    average_cultivation_area = data.groupby('Crop Name')['Area Under Cultivation (UOM:Ha(Hectares))'].mean().round(3)
    
    final_table2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'Crop Name': average_yield.index,
        'Average Yield (Kg/Ha)': average_yield.values,
        'Average Cultivation Area (Ha)': average_cultivation_area.values
    })
    
    # Prepare the JSON response
    response = {
        "final_table": final_table.to_dict(orient="records"),
        "final_table2": final_table2.to_dict(orient="records")
    }

    # Debugging prints
    print("Final Table 1:", final_table)
    print("Final Table 2:", final_table2)
    print("Resulting data structure:", response)

    # Return the JSON response
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Below are the images of the output:
]
]

How can I make tables visible on the screen?

Are there any javascript errors? Is your response coming back as text or json?

There are no javascript error. The response is coming in json format

@whizzx Are you sure the React code is just a copy paste of the one you are using?
I tested it by mocking the API call, getting the data from a local .json file, and it works.
If you want to try: save the json data to a data.json file in the public folder of your React project and then mock the API call with const response = await axios.get('data.json');. Does it work then?

Yes , the code is complete copy, paste. Can there be any problem in flask-server files?
response = await axios.get('data.json'); => making this change gives error 404.

If you want to acces the dataset. Below is my github link.https://github.com/ishaj72/CropData/tree/master/flask-server/Dataset

Your code looks fine. You should debug the data in your react component with console.log(). Log what tables.final_table.length is, etc. you should be able to fully debug this without asking stackoverflow. React doesn’t do anything magic, there is nothing hidden happening. If your ternary expressions are false it’s because you have bad data. Or you’re ignoring a JavaScript error
